# Ruby command not recognized after installing it with rvm

Tags: software-installation, ruby, rvm

I followed this tutorial to install ruby with rvm: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

The problem is that everytime that I log in, the ruby installation is not recognized, for example if I try executing a ruby script with the "ruby" command this is what I get:

[image]

To make it be recognized I have to run this command:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

But every time I login I have to do it again.

Comment: This article may help you [Setup Ruby On Rails on
Ubuntu](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Ruby by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

See the [Doc](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#apt).

Answer (score 5):

#### What went wrong?

During installation, `rvm` puts two lines (*first one is a comment though*) in `~/.bash_profile` file to help `bash` recognize ruby binaries. But the problem is Ubuntu's `bash` ignores this file. As a result, it doesn't know that you already installed ruby and prompts you to install ruby!

The problem can be solved in two different way.

---

#### Solution 1: Using `~/.bashrc` file

Open your `~/.bashrc` file and put these two lines (or last one) there.

```bsh
### Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

---

#### Solution 2: Make the regular shell session as *login shell*

Or you can turn on your virtual terminal's preference to consider the shell as *Login Shell*. The settings can be found in -

- **Gnome Terminal**: Menu > *Edit* > *Profile Preference* > *Command* Tab > *Run command as a login shell*
- **Mate Terminal**: Menu > *Edit* > *Profile Preference* > *Title & Command* Tab > *Run command as a login shell*
- **Xfce4 Terminal**: Menu > *Edit* > *Preference* > *General* Tab > *Run command as login shell*

Either one will do the job.

---

Another solution could be installing Ruby in System using Ubuntu's repository. But that defeats the purpose of using `rvm` at first place.

Comment: This is the answer to the question asked. Why is it not the accepted answer?

Comment: @TonyCronin This is added after 2 years, The OP might not active now. I appreciate your support though. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This will install old version of ruby (1.9) currently existing in Ubuntu repos.
You might want to check installation from [source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source)

Download ruby tar from [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and then run:

```
$ tar -xf ruby-your-downloaded-package
$ cd ruby_extracted_directory
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

In some cases you will need to realod bash by typing:

```
$ bash
```