# my bash terminal is showing unwanted message when starting

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby

`bash: source: /home/vj/.rvm/scripts/rvm: is a directory`

Recently I tried to install ruby on my PC. And after that installation every time am starting my terminal it is showing the above message. I want to remove it because it's pretty annoying...I am new to Ubuntu so don't know much about it... So my only hope is you guys in the community

Comment: Check if that directory is mentioned in your `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: I reinstalled Ruby using rvm and that line has gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an equivalent of the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file (taken from [Ruby command not recognized after installing it with rvm](https://askubuntu.com/q/624610/29012)):

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Delete or comment out that line.  You can comment it out by placing a `#` in front of the line.  The comment will allow you to fix it if you decide to continue with your Ruby installation/configuration at a later time.

It's that line that is running every time you start your terminal.

Comment: Another option is to test if the file exists before running it. ie something like `if [[ -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then`