# Bash Terminal showing unwanted text on opening

Tags: command-line, bash, themes

My terminal is showing the text copied below on opening. I think, though can't be sure, that this started happening after I installed a theme for the first time. Can you help me to remove this?

My .bashrc doesn't contain anything that would directly print this text.

I have run `grep LS_COLORS . -r` from insides /usr/share/themes/ Nothing was matched.

Related: [my bash terminal is showing unwanted message when starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021047/my-bash-terminal-is-showing-unwanted-message-when-starting) (answer not applicable here).

update: The same text displays again after running `source ~/.bashrc`

Update 2: Dircolors being run in bashrc:

```
# downloaded feb 2021
eval 'dircolors /home/neil/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized/dircolors'


# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

Thanks

LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=34:ow=34;40:ln=35:pi=30;44:so=35;44:do=35;44:bd=33;44:cd=37;44:or=05;37;41:mi=05;37;41:ex=01;31:*.cmd=01;31:*.exe=01;31:*.com=01;31:*.bat=01;31:*.reg=01;31:*.app=01;31:*.txt=32:*.org=32:*.md=32:*.mkd=32:*.h=32:*.hpp=32:*.c=32:*.C=32:*.cc=32:*.cpp=32:*.cxx=32:*.objc=32:*.cl=32:*.sh=32:*.bash=32:*.csh=32:*.zsh=32:*.el=32:*.vim=32:*.java=32:*.pl=32:*.pm=32:*.py=32:*.rb=32:*.hs=32:*.php=32:*.htm=32:*.html=32:*.shtml=32:*.erb=32:*.haml=32:*.xml=32:*.rdf=32:*.css=32:*.sass=32:*.scss=32:*.less=32:*.js=32:*.coffee=32:*.man=32:*.0=32:*.1=32:*.2=32:*.3=32:*.4=32:*.5=32:*.6=32:*.7=32:*.8=32:*.9=32:*.l=32:*.n=32:*.p=32:*.pod=32:*.tex=32:*.go=32:*.sql=32:*.csv=32:*.sv=32:*.svh=32:*.v=32:*.vh=32:*.vhd=32:*.bmp=33:*.cgm=33:*.dl=33:*.dvi=33:*.emf=33:*.eps=33:*.gif=33:*.jpeg=33:*.jpg=33:*.JPG=33:*.mng=33:*.pbm=33:*.pcx=33:*.pdf=33:*.pgm=33:*.png=33:*.PNG=33:*.ppm=33:*.pps=33:*.ppsx=33:*.ps=33:*.svg=33:*.svgz=33:*.tga=33:*.tif=33:*.tiff=33:*.xbm=33:*.xcf=33:*.xpm=33:*.xwd=33:*.xwd=33:*.yuv=33:*.nef=33:*.NEF=33:*.aac=33:*.au=33:*.flac=33:*.m4a=33:*.mid=33:*.midi=33:*.mka=33:*.mp3=33:*.mpa=33:*.mpeg=33:*.mpg=33:*.ogg=33:*.opus=33:*.ra=33:*.wav=33:*.anx=33:*.asf=33:*.avi=33:*.axv=33:*.flc=33:*.fli=33:*.flv=33:*.gl=33:*.m2v=33:*.m4v=33:*.mkv=33:*.mov=33:*.MOV=33:*.mp4=33:*.mp4v=33:*.mpeg=33:*.mpg=33:*.nuv=33:*.ogm=33:*.ogv=33:*.ogx=33:*.qt=33:*.rm=33:*.rmvb=33:*.swf=33:*.vob=33:*.webm=33:*.wmv=33:*.doc=31:*.docx=31:*.rtf=31:*.odt=31:*.dot=31:*.dotx=31:*.ott=31:*.xls=31:*.xlsx=31:*.ods=31:*.ots=31:*.ppt=31:*.pptx=31:*.odp=31:*.otp=31:*.fla=31:*.psd=31:*.7z=1;35:*.apk=1;35:*.arj=1;35:*.bin=1;35:*.bz=1;35:*.bz2=1;35:*.cab=1;35:*.deb=1;35:*.dmg=1;35:*.gem=1;35:*.gz=1;35:*.iso=1;35:*.jar=1;35:*.msi=1;35:*.rar=1;35:*.rpm=1;35:*.tar=1;35:*.tbz=1;35:*.tbz2=1;35:*.tgz=1;35:*.tx=1;35:*.war=1;35:*.xpi=1;35:*.xz=1;35:*.z=1;35:*.Z=1;35:*.zip=1;35:*.zst=1;35:*.ANSI-30-black=30:*.ANSI-01;30-brblack=01;30:*.ANSI-31-red=31:*.ANSI-01;31-brred=01;31:*.ANSI-32-green=32:*.ANSI-01;32-brgreen=01;32:*.ANSI-33-yellow=33:*.ANSI-01;33-bryellow=01;33:*.ANSI-34-blue=34:*.ANSI-01;34-brblue=01;34:*.ANSI-35-magenta=35:*.ANSI-01;35-brmagenta=01;35:*.ANSI-36-cyan=36:*.ANSI-01;36-brcyan=01;36:*.ANSI-37-white=37:*.ANSI-01;37-brwhite=01;37:*.log=01;32:*~=01;32:*#=01;32:*.bak=01;33:*.BAK=01;33:*.old=01;33:*.OLD=01;33:*.org_archive=01;33:*.off=01;33:*.OFF=01;33:*.dist=01;33:*.DIST=01;33:*.orig=01;33:*.ORIG=01;33:*.swp=01;33:*.swo=01;33:*.v=01;33:*.gpg=34:*.gpg=34:*.pgp=34:*.asc=34:*.3des=34:*.aes=34:*.enc=34:*.sqlite=34:';
export LS_COLORS

Comment: Please share the contents of your .bashrc - it looks like it runs `dircolors` somehow.

Comment: @ArturMeinild question updated with relevant part of bashrc. Think you're on to something, since there's a comment there saying it changed this month...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the evaluation in "command substitution", like this:

```
eval "$(dircolors /home/neil/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized/dircolors)"
```

Then it should work without displaying the output (the same way it's written in your `.bashrc` under the `# enable color support` section).

Comment: Perfect thank you. I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: The `'` characters should be `\`` in your original `eval ...` statement - this is an OLDER form of `$( ... )`